# Reducing rent costs

Tags: anchor, pda, rent, storage

I feel like for some base accounts, I’m getting charged 0.002 sol, which is like $0.20 to store a simple data field on a PDA.

Especially for multiple data fields I want to store, this number added over and over again adds up.

A few related questions:
1: does firedancer or future work on solana work to decrease this by a few orders of magnitude? Would be great to have < $0.001 for simple field storage on PDAs… the cheaper we go, the more new UIUX we unlock

2: if I create a PDA that isn’t rent exempt, what happens when the rent expires? Does the account disappear? What’s the best way to simulate this in anchor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Firedancer won't directly affect rent, as this is decided on the protocol layer. There is talk around reducing rent though, such as [SIMD-0101](https://github.com/solana-foundation/solana-improvement-documents/pull/101).
2. You can't create an Account without enough rent to make it rent exempt which in turn means rent isn't collected and can't "expire". If you try to create a PDAs with a balance below the rent-exempt amount, your transaction will fail. Furthermore, if you try to remove lamports from an Account that is rent-exempt, one of two things will happen:

- Removing so the balance is less than the rent exempt amount but more than 0: Your tx will fail.
- Removing all lamports: Your PDA will be closed & purged.

More on rent can be found here: [Is rent collected on Solana?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/8310/is-rent-collected-on-solana/8311#8311)

Also would like to add if high rent costs are a problem for you, look into [state compression](https://docs.solana.com/learn/state-compression) to potentially reduce the space your data takes up.